# Save the value of "another variable" when I run the random function

Tags: python

guys.

I'm trying to implement this logical condition in Python. I have to choose between a random number from 0 to 1 but save them both in two variables, so that the first variable is the value I'm interested in, while in the second there's the other value.

Something like:

```
x, y = random.sample(0,1)
```

But it's not working. How can I do it?

Comment: this syntax is wrong. sample takes 2 arguments an iterable and an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. It selects two values from [0, 1] without repetitions:

```
import random

x, y = random.sample([0, 1], 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = random.sample(0, 1)
y = random.sample(0, 1)
```

doing this might just make a way to simply make 2 separate values with 2 different lines.

Comment: No. The values ​​must be different, I simply have to save both in one operation.

Comment: which IDE are you using

Comment: Your code causes `ValueError`. The first argument (population) can't be just a single number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `shuffle` method:

```py
import random

results = [0, 1]
random.shuffle(results)
x = results[0]
y = results[1]
```

Comment: I've seen it done with a single line of code (using `random,sample`). This solution seems cumbersome to me

Comment: If you only have two values, you can do `x = random.sample(0, 1)` and then `y = 1 - x`